# How to add LongPressGestureRecognizer into disabled TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have TextField that `isEnabled = false`,

now I am trying to add `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

inside UITableViewCell :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let tap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: userNameTextField, action: #selector(userNamelongPressAction))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

but I get crash

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField
>   userNamelongPressAction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

what can I do?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a common mistake, you are adding the target wrongly to `UITextField`, instead you must set target to where you implement the method `userNamelongPressAction`

this code is assuming that you have implemented `userNamelongPressAction` method in this class context

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let tap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(userNamelongPressAction))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: but this will set the hole tableview cell as target, so I should subclass UITextView and implement this method over there?

Comment: where you have userNamelongPressAction implemented?

Comment: inside UITableViewCell

Comment: you are adding your Gesture to your TableViewCell to show again your UITextField? so your TableViewCell must be the target because your UITextField is a subview i think that my answer is just fine for your requirements, don't work properly?

Comment: nope, because I have more then one UITextView in my cell, and for each one I need to set separate action..

Comment: Ok @Felix but you remember your question is about? my answer solves your question